# What event can be used to detect embedded chart resized by widening column?

Tags: excel, vba, events, charts, resize

I have two embedded charts on the same worksheet, equally wide and one above the other. Their positioning is "move and size with cells". They extend from column AO to BE inclusive. When I resize a column close to the right edge of both charts (by dragging the BE/BF column boundary in the bar at the top with the column letters in it), both charts resize at once, which is what I want. This is a simple and intuitive way for the spreadsheet user to resize two similar charts at once without the trouble of selecting them. The problem is, Excel does not layout the resized charts exactly as I want, so I want to trap chart resize events in VBA in order to tweak the chart layout afterwards. My problem is that this way of resizing the charts does not trigger any chart resize events (I was hoping for two such events, one for each chart).

I have implemented event handling in VBA as described by Jon Peltier at https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/ . All the app and chart events he describes are working for me. In particular, if I resize a single chart by clicking on its border and dragging the border, I trap a resize event successfully. However, the problem described at the outset still occurs if I delete one of the two charts and resize the remaining single chart by not selecting it but moving the column boundary near its border -- i.e. the problem described initially occurs regardless of whether one chart or two charts are resized in this way. So I'm guessing that the essence of the problem is that resize events are not being triggered when chart resizing is done without selecting the chart(s).

This leads me to ask if, by way of a workaround, there is any other event that can be trapped when a column is resized. I have tried all the events available in Peltier's ClsChartEvent module, and also all worksheet events, and found none that are triggered by column resize. I'd be glad to hear if anyone knows of a way to trap any event at all that allows detection of a chart resize or column resize.

I am using Excel 2010 and have verified that my problem also exists in Excel 2021. I can provide my event handling VBA code if necessary, but given that some chart resize events are working correctly (as are all the events in Peltier's sample code) that seems unnecessary at the moment. I attach a screenshot of the worksheet with the two embedded charts and the drag location.

Comment: I don't believe there is an event to handle a column resizing event. The reason the event is not triggered when not selecting the chart is because the change events are linked only to changes made directly by the user, not even vba changes. The only solution I can think of for you is to use the worksheet_selection event to detect if any of the cells in the area of either chart is selected, then trigger a check of both charts that they are aligned and with the same size, else change x to match y or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I see what you mean: Excel thinks that the widening of the chart caused by widening a nearby column is just a side effect; it cannot tell that the widening of the chart is the whole purpose of the column resize, and so it does not see this action as meriting a chart-resize event.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about the worksheet selection event, but it does not really help me, I think. The chart-&-column-widening action I described does not need any cells anywhere near the chart/s to be selected. Whatever selection exists at the time is irrelevant to this action, since the widening is done by dragging the column boundary in the column names bar and requires no specific selection. I could of course use every worksheet selection event to check the chart layout as you suggest, but there is still no guarantee that the user will change the selection after widening the chart/s.